# async in map with callback won't work file be still undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, typescript, asynchronous

hello all I have some problems with my async function the test will be undefined what am I doing wrong I need help with this it's so frustrating

```js
async function fileToObj(jsonOfXls){
    const promises = jsonOfXls.Blad1.map(async x => {
      let test;
      await base64.encode(`pdfs/${x.E}`,  function (err, base64String) {
        test = base64String
      })
      return { gtin: x.D, gln: x.C, order: x.B, file: test }
    })
    const output = await Promise.all(promises)
   console.log(output)
}
```

i try now this :

```js
async function fileToObj(jsonOfXls) {
  const output = await Promise.all(
    jsonOfXls.Blad1.map(async x => {
      const file = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        base64.encode(`pdfs/${x.E}`, function(err, base64String) {
          if (err != null) {
            return reject(err)
          }
          resolve(base64String)
        })
      })
      return { gtin: x.D, gln: x.C, order: x.B, file }
    })
  )
  console.log(output)
}
```

but i get this error:

72) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: encode fail
(node:8772) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (reject
ion id: 1)

Comment: The way you call `base64.encode` looks like you mix both styles, i.e. you still have the callback there. I'd remove the callback, i.e. I would replace this whole line with `let test = await base64.encode(`pdfs/${x.E}`);`. This of course works only if the api returns a promise.

Answer (score 1):

You can only usefully await a promise.

`base64.encode` takes a callback which implies it **doesn't** return a promise.

Awaiting its return value therefore has no practical effect.

You would need to [wrap it in a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) before you can await it.

Comment: i try now this :
```js
async function fileToObj(jsonOfXls) {
  const output = await Promise.all(
    jsonOfXls.Blad1.map(async x => {
      const file = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        base64.encode(`pdfs/${x.E}`, function(err, base64String) {
          if (err != null) {
            return reject(err)
          }
          resolve(base64String)
        })
      })
      return { gtin: x.D, gln: x.C, order: x.B, file }
    })
  )
  console.log(output)
}
```